# Cassandra java.io.IOException: Map failed for COMMIT-LOG-ALLOCATOR

Tags: cassandra

When total size of the commit log directory exceedes above the 680 Mb it throws this exception

```
ERROR [COMMIT-LOG-ALLOCATOR] 2012-07-04 15:04:57,070 AbstractCassandraDaemon.java (line 134) Exception in thread Thread[COMMIT-LOG-ALLOCATOR,5,main]
java.io.IOError: java.io.IOException: Map failed
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegment.<init>(CommitLogSegment.java:127)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogAllocator$3.run(CommitLogAllocator.java:203)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogAllocator$1.runMayThrow(CommitLogAllocator.java:95)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Map failed
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegment.<init>(CommitLogSegment.java:119)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Map failed
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map0(Native Method)
    ... 6 more
ERROR [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2012-07-04 15:04:57,075 AbstractCassandraDaemon.java (line 134) Exception in thread Thread[StorageServiceShutdownHook,5,main]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.stop(Gossiper.java:1132)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService$2.runMayThrow(StorageService.java:489)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your operating system you should change the `-Xmx` and `-Xms` parameters of Java VM.

I personally run cassandra on windows so I've changed `%CASSANDRA_HOME%/bin/cassandra.bat` lines 34 and 35 from `1G` to `100M`.

Comment: I am not sure if our cases are the same. In my case  it was https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4201?focusedCommentId=13266183&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13266183

Answer (score 3):

This means that you've run out of address space to map commitlog segments into.

Best solution: upgrade to a 64bit JVM.

Worse solution: in cassandra.yaml, set commitlog_segment_size_in_mb and commitlog_total_space_in_mb both to 16.

This isn't the first time this has come up; I've opened https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4422 to improve the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Well ,I had the same issue and my whole day got wasted, but I could not update it to 64 bit JVM because my Ubuntu Machine was 32 bit.

@jbellis : Suggestion from him helped a lot ,I reduced the commitlog_total_space_in_mb to 128 mb.

But even after applying this, i still got the error. I solved this and made cassandra work by deleting the Cassandra folder which contains(commitlog, data and saved_caches) in /var/lib directory.

** Note : try this only if you have unnecessary data in the commit log folder ( data which you don't need )